# Error in trying to parse youtube with htmlagility pack to c#

Tags: c#, .net, parsing, html-agility-pack

I am building an application when i want to parse some data from youtube playlist using `HtmlAbilityPack`:
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLDx6vxaCLeUTw0NRQhgYwCaWVf9j-N02Q

And i want to use this data in my WPF application. For examle - name of playlist: `"Top Hit 2021 ~ Chill Songs ~ At My Wors x Monter x Beautiful Scar" in this case.` Buy my xpath expressions everytime return me null. But when i try to check it on different xpath-testers - it works. But in my application it doesnt work

For example:

```
    HtmlWeb webDoc = new HtmlWeb();
            HtmlDocument docFirst = webDoc.Load("https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLDx6vxaCLeUTw0NRQhgYwCaWVf9j-N02Q");

// and my title field = null.
            var title = docFirst.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(".//*[@id='title']/yt-formatted-string/a/text()");
```

And I dont know how to fix it

Comment: Perhaps comparing the document from your tests with the document you are receiving in `docFirst` will help. Make sure they are actually structured the same. Otherwise, you may need to add more code in order to add context for a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get always `null` because the document you loaded in `docFirst` variable doesn't have the node you are looking for. That happens because the html page must be rendered first, using a JS engine. A common way to go is to use Selenium (or any other automation framework, e.g Playwright).

This is an example using Selenium + Html Agility Pack, but you can ommit HAP:

```
var driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLDx6vxaCLeUTw0NRQhgYwCaWVf9j-N02Q");

// In a real world scenario you will, most likely, use
// the built-in selenium wait methods
Console.ReadLine();

// Also here, you probably need to close any popup might appear.
// This could be done by clicking on a button for example.
// Take a look to the selenium official page.

// In order to make this sample code to work, 
// click manually if there is any popup and press enter in console window.

// And finally you will get the page source code that includes
// the title you are looking for.
var src = driver.PageSource;
var htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
htmlDoc.LoadHtml(src);

var title = htmlDoc.DocumentNode
                   .SelectSingleNode("//*[@id='title']/yt-formatted-string/a")
                   .InnerHtml;

Console.WriteLine(title);
```

[Selenium official page](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/)